# Remove package on centOS

Tags: oracle, centos, uninstallation

Helloo,
I have a prblem with centOS
I try to uninstall oracle instant client. When I do 'yum list install' It's write that the package is installed, but when I try to remove 'rpm -e oracle...' it's say that the package is not installed.
How to remove the package of the list ?

regards

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, we are a programming community, not a software support team. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, In find the solution  ;)